# Eclipse 03-2021 and -data @noDefault

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

In order to run an Eclipse RCP App. from eclipse IDE in run or debug mode, one need to put ***-data @noDefault*** in command line. Once the RCP App. is built with Maven/Tycho, I thought this option was no longer needed.

I've upgraded Eclipse IDE form 06 2020 to 03 2021 (Mac OS 10.14.6), and now I need to put this option in command line even in the built product to not have this exception :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-06-03 07:44:13.280
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change the location once it is set.
```

***Maven repo : https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03/***

Is-it a normal behavior ? Am-I doing the wrong way ?

Comment: I don't need to specify that in my e4 RCPs so you may be doing something wrong - but you need to give us a lot more info to work out what.

Comment: I am using Eclipse RCP Legacy. I was doing something the wrong way : trying to access preferences in main bundle activator (constructor - BTW preferences were stalled). Moving this access to postStartup() solved problems. Sorry for that.

Comment: And you're wright no need to specify -data option. Don't really understand the link between my early access to preferences and this option...